# Possibility to put a search button on toolbar but only for home view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I describe my problem (i'm new in kotlin)...

I want to put a button search on the toolbar in kotlin because it's nice compare to a search view.
But when i try to do this the button search it's available for all view (Home, upload, settings by navigation bar)

It's possible to create a condition "just for home view show search button in toolbar"?

Comment: Add the search view in the Home Screen Fragment menu, then it will show only in Home Fragment other screens it will not show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your home view fragment, add your search item to the menu, so when that fragment is displayed its search option is present in the menn

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    // put your search menu item in this menu file
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_view, menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_search -> doSearchThing()
        ...
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    return true
}
```

and you need to tell the system that this fragment wants to mess with the menu:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    ...
}
```

If your "home view" is an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`, so you only want to show the search button if certain fragments **aren't being displayed**, you'll have to put some logic in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to decide whether to `removeItem` the search button from the menu, and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` whenever the fragments change and you need to work out whether to show the button again

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have a toolbar at the activity level, and then several fragments which represent the different screens handled by your navigation bar.

If I understood your problem correctly, you want, just when the home section is selected, that the toolbar shows the search button on the toolbar, and maybe other buttons or none for the other sections.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            invalidateOptionsMenu()
            true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        return when(navView.selectedItemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home ->  {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu)
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_dashboard -> {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu)
                true
            }
            R.id.navigation_notifications -> {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_notifications, menu)
                true
            }
            else -> {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> menu_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Do search" />
</menu>
```

> menu_dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

> menu_notificationx.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>
```

NOTE: I'm not using the navigation library here, not sure if it's your case

Another solution is set the toolbar menu, just for the home section